# How to pass a sub-matrix as a parameter

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a recursive function that performs a specific task. The function receives a single parameter of an Integer matrix. Is there a way to pass a sub-matrix as parameter during a consequent function call, in a way that is similar to advancing the pointer to an array (Let `arr[10]` be our array. Then performing `arr += 1` will advance the beginning of the array one index forward.

Additionally, the function's signature can't changed.

Example:

```
void f(int matrix[N][N])
{
    // Some code here
    f(matrix+1);
}
```

Comment: Your best bet is probably to add an index to the current matrix into f(), e.g. `void f(int matrix[N][N], int level)`

Comment: @paulsm4 Forgot to mention that the function's signature cannot be changed. Edited the post.

Comment: A C array is a contiguous sequence of elements. A sub-array is generally not (except in the 1-dimensional case) so the two types are not compatible. If you cannot change the function, then you'll need to make a copy of the sub-matrix and pass that as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to pass a sub-matrix as parameter during a consequent function call

No, but you can pass a description of the sub-matrix to take. For instance, you can pass the pointer to the outer matrix and 4 parameters that describe the offset of the sub-matrix and its size.

Answer (score 0):

If changing the function signature is not allowed, you could maintain a global variable to keep track of the index counter:

```
int cN = 0;
void f(int m[N][N])
{
    printf("%d\n", m[cN][0]);
    if(cN < N - 1)
    {
        cN++;
        f(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh. That's pretty ugly hack there...  Clearly, the OP is trying to do something the original function was never designed for.  The OP has exactly two choices: 1) change the method, or 2) write a new method with, and call the new method wherever/whenever possible.